# jQuery - replace (text) content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, frontend

- ### SCENARIO

I have the following HTML code snippet:

```
<div class="container">
    TEXT
    <p> PARAGRAPH 1 </p>
    <p> PARAGRAPH 2 </p>
    <p> PARAGRAPH 3 </p>
    <p> PARAGRAPH 4 </p>
</div>
```

I am required to change the plain text using JS/jQuery, using the HTML DOM methods.

- ### PROBLEM

** I can access the "plain text" node using

```
document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].childNodes[0]
```

** However, I can't use the `innerHTML`, as it returns "`undefined`":

```
document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML
```

** Using the `replaceChild` method doesn't work either (it triggers an `Uncaught DOMException` at the console log).

```
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("THE TEXT HAS BEEN REPLACED");
    
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].childNodes[0];

    item.replaceChild(textnode, item);
```

** And finally, using

```
document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].innerHTML
```

selects all the HTML content inside `<div class="container">`.

Is there any way I can access the text content of "TEXT" and change it dynamically?

- ### JSFIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/kouk/4otbqc75/

Comment: I know it is bad practice displaying unformatted plain text like that, but I am required to handle this situation. If I could, I would simply add some HTML tags, however, I don't have a choice on this situation.

Comment: Use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: you can use regex for this.

Comment: Just a tip: stop using `alert()` for debugging. `console.dir()` would have given a strong hint about what property to change.

Comment: Oh, I was directly debugging my code via the Chrome console; I should have also placed `console.dir`in my jsfiddle... thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].childNodes[0].textContent = "New Text";
```

Comment: `textContent` should not be used to `set`, but to `get` text, as it represents the text content of a node and all its descendants. In this example it works as the node `TEXT` has no children (but the rule still stands).

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rnqd7tL4/3/)

```
$(".container").html($(".container:first-child").html().replace("TEXT","TEXT CHANGED"));
```

Comment: I would do that if I could change the HTML file; sadly, I can't change that code (I can only use JS/jQuery)

Comment: ah ok 2 minutes i give you a solution

Comment: check the updated answer